# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql

I have trying to create a login form and come across the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''; ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

```
$mypassword='.$_POST['mypassword']';
```

how can i solve it

many thanks

Comment: Do you see something on the right side of this page which says **Related**?

Comment: i have come across new errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are using **`'`** under **`'`**. You have to use **`"`** under **`'`** or **`'`** under **`"`** or you can escape it by **`/`**

Convert this

```
$mypassword='.$_POST['mypassword']';
```

to this

```
$mypassword=$_POST["mypassword"];
```

Comment: it still appear the same error

Comment: thanks. i have check